# How to search my bucket to see if a certain file exists

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's my s3 session:

```
img = request.FILES.get('image')

filename = random_string()

"""if filename exists in my s3 bucket:
    create another random_string"""

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='media/%s' % img.name, Body=img)
```

Basically when I upload a file via AJAX, as per the code above, I generate a random filename. However before using this filename for the new uploaded image, I want to check that it doesn't exist, to prevent overlap. If it does exist, then try another random string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

How good is your random function?  If it is possible, I would recommend using a [UUID generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to come up with file names, and assume no collisions (or assume eventual collisions, and follow the next steps).

Regarding how to tell if a key already exists, I would expect you can just perform a 'get-object' for the given generated key.  If you get something back, then there is an object there already and a new key should be generated and tested.

Note that this approach is not an atomic operation, and would leave a window for the key to be generated elsewhere (assuming multiple concurrent executions is possible) and placed into the S3 bucket between check and put.  It is because of this possibility that I recommend a UUID generator in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `random_string()` function. Maybe cache the results of your random strings and verify that the string you are about to return has not been used before returning.

Comment: yeah that's probably a more efficient way, however what is a good way to cache the results without creating a new model field?

Comment: why can't you persist a local copy of the filenames that have already been used before adding the filename to the s3 bucket?